# Are the episodes of An Idiot Abroad out of order?

Tags: production, an-idiot-abroad

While watching An Idiot Abroad, in one episode Karl has a break down over riding a camel.  A couple of episodes later her rides a different camel and seems relatively ok with it.  This attitude seems to contradict the previous episode and it made us wonder if one was filmed before the other.

The episodes in particular are Petra and the Great Pyramid of Giza.

Were the episodes released different from filming order?  If so, what order were they filmed in?

Comment: I do suspect some of those scenes were artistic license. I recall one where he stormed out of a hotel, refusing to stay there, but in the street he had absolutely no belongings (bags, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue doesn't seem to be camels *per se* but rather the amount of time he has spend (and is being asked to spend) on one when there are perfectly good roads they could drive on instead.